# How to get string after the last '/' character using a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to fetch last part of the string after character `/` which in our example is `'PAYLINK STALE CHECK ENTRI'`.

Also, please note that, `'PAYLINK STALE CHECK ENTRI'` is not a static string.

Example:

```
:61:1511171116CR00,10NMSC566666666/15139333333333333/CTC/MSC/PAYLINK STALE CHECK ENTRI
```

The output should be

```
PAYLINK STALE CHECK ENTRI
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regex to do this, just use [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to find the last `/` and [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to get the substring after it.

```js
var str = '103150800130001/CTC/MSC/PAYLINK STALE CHECK ENTRI';

console.log(str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/')+1));
```

However, if you prefer a regex-based solution, this would work to strip off everything from the last `/` and before:

```js
var str = '103150800130001/CTC/MSC/PAYLINK STALE CHECK ENTRI';

console.log(str.replace(/.*\//, ''));
```